# Will thicker o-ring stop this faucet leak?

Tags: leak, faucet

My countertop dishwasher requires attaching an adapter to the kitchen faucet. My landlord replaced the faucet yesterday (which had a leak in another place regardless of dishwasher). Now when I attach my dishwasher hose and turn on the water, water leaks between the adapter and the faucet. It doesn't leak with the aerator it came with.

**Do I need a thicker o-ring for the adapter?** The ring the adapter came with already reaches above the threads.

(I'm guessing this wasn't a problem with the old faucet because the pressure was lower.)

Left: dishwasher adapter. Right: aerator the faucet came with
[image: Left: dishwasher adapter. Right: aerator the faucet came with]

Faucet with adapter and dishwasher hose attached
[image: Faucet with adapter and dishwasher hose attached]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to tighten it more. I bought a better wrench,  tightened it more, and now it doesn't leak.

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things. Don't forget to mark your answer as "the" answer.

Comment: yes, just watch out that you dont over-tighten, normally the fittings are brass underneath and the slightest bit of overtightening leads to a nice crack.  If you still have issues, you could also consider a little bit of plumbers tape around the thread.

Answer (score 1):

The first repair to try and stop the leak is to use teflon plumbers tape that you can get from any hardware store. Unscrew the part that leaks (it should have male threads). Wrap the threads with the tape by raveling the tape in a clockwise rotation (from the perspective with the threads facing you). 2-3 full wraps should do. Tighten the part by hand than with a wrench another 1/8-1/4 turn.